# How to export copyq clipboard history to a file?

Tags: clipboard-manager

According to CopyQ documentation, I can use `copyq exportData FILENAME` to export the clipboard history from copyq. However, the histoy file is something like this:

```
\00\00\00CopyQ v2\00\00\00\00&\00c\00l\00i\00p\00b\00o\00a\00r\00d\00\00\00&\FF\FF\FF\FE\00\00\00\00\00\00\005\00\00\00\00\82<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><span class="st"><em>le</em>.txt <em>copyq copy</em> tex</span>\00\00\00\004\00\00\00\00le.t
```

How to export clipboard data in "readable" file?